# How to handle potentially large email lists?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, spam, html-email, email-spam

We have a micro site that is being distributed via email. This microsite has a form on it that allows you to specify x amount of email addresses to forward the microsite.

- What are our spam concerns?
- Can we use an api to handle the email sending? If so, who provides such a service?
- Could we alleviate spam concerns by limiting the amount of addresses you can forward to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using an internal solution, however the solution i eventually found was sendgrid.com, for anyone referencing this question in the future.